# How do I return the ID field in a related table in Laravel request

Tags: laravel

I have two related tables and I want to return all fields including the ID (key) field. My query below returns all fields except the ID. how do I return the ID field from one of the tables?

```
'programmes' => ProgrammeInstances::with('programmes')->get(),
```

the query below returns Unknown column 'programmes.programme_title' as it is looking for it in the table 'programme_instances'

```
'programmes' => ProgrammeInstances::with('programmes')->select('programmes.programme_title', 'programmeInstances.id', 'programmeInstances.name', 'programmeInstances.year')->get(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a solution i found below - still not sure why ID isnt automatically returned when i get all fields, but works when i specify individual fields:

```
'programmes' => ProgrammeInstances::with('programmes')
    ->get()
    ->transform(fn ($prog) => [
      'programme_title' => $prog->programmes->programme_title,
      'id' => $prog->id,
      'name' => $prog->name,
      'year' => $prog->year,
]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides multiple relationships, one of these is the `hasMany()` relationship which should return a collection where a `User` hasMany rows inside of your database

For example, inside your User model :

```
public function programmes() {
  return $this->hasMany(Program::class);
}
```

Now in your controller, you can do :

```
public function edit($id) {
  $programmes = User::find($id)->with('programmes')->get();

  return view('user.edit')->with('programmes', $programmes);
}
```

And then you can loop over it inside your view

```
@forelse($programmes->programmes as $program)
   // provide the data
@empty 
  // the user doesn’t have any programmes
@endforelse
```

Comment: thanks, but my table relationship isn't users, and my issue is around not being able to return the id field